# How can I copy files from parameterised directory using maven archetypes?

Tags: maven-3, maven-archetype

I need to copy files from a parameterised local directory to a specific directory inside the project. I currently have this archetype-metadata.xml.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<archetype-descriptor
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-descriptor/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/archetype-descriptor-1.0.0.xsd"
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-descriptor/1.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        name="custom-maven-archetype">
        <fileSets>
                <fileSet filtered="true" packaged="true" encoding="UTF-8">
                        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                </fileSet>
                <fileSet filtered="true" packaged="true" encoding="UTF-8">
                        <directory>src/test/java</directory>
                </fileSet>
                <fileSet filtered="true" packaged="true" encodind="UTF-8">
                        <directory>${wsdlFile}</directory>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}</outputDirectory>
                </fileSet>
        </fileSets>
        <requiredProperties>
                <requiredProperty key="codigoMunicipal" />
                <requiredProperty key="wsdlFile" />
        </requiredProperties>
</archetype-descriptor>
```

This is my current filetree.

```
.
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   └── main
│       └── resources
│           ├── META-INF
│           │   └── maven
│           │       └── archetype-metadata.xml
│           └── archetype-resources
│               ├── README.md
│               └── pom.xml
└── target
    ├── agency-lib-archetype-1.0.0.jar
    └── classes
        ├── META-INF
        │   └── maven
        │       └── archetype-metadata.xml
        └── archetype-resources
            ├── README.md
            └── pom.xml
```

Comment: Is it possible to share the entire project?

Did you run maven using the -X option.

Why is wsdlFile dynamic in nature?

Comment: It is dynamic because the wsdlFile is obtained from external sources. This is a project for invoice creation on cities webservices. Cities in Brazil don't have resilient or even consistent services, so downloading automatically is out of the question. So, our workflow consists of downloading the wsdl and the xsds and putting them inside the project manually. I wanted to remove all manual labor possible.
Also, this kinda is the entire project. I'm just missing the wsdl and the xsds on the resources folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the archetype-post-generate.groovy to copy it manually

See the Post-Generation Script at the end of this page https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/advanced-usage.html

Comment: This is really interesting. Gonna check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Create a src/main/resources/META-INF/archetype-post-generate.groovy file as mentioned by the other 2 answers and by https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/advanced-usage.html#Post-generation_script note that this is not in the same folder as src/main/resources/META-INF/maven/archetype-metadata.xml .

The archetype-post-generate.groovy will run after archetype:generate creates the files.

Below is a sample script:

```java
//file:noinspection GrPackage
/*
This groovy script has access to a var named request which is a ArchetypeGenerationRequest (https://maven.apache.org/archetype/archetype-common/apidocs/org/apache/maven/archetype/ArchetypeGenerationRequest.html),
which has getProperties() and other methods. Each of the keys of getProperties() also exist as variables.
*/
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Paths
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption

println "Start of archetype-post-generate.groovy"
String newRepoDir = "${request.outputDirectory}/${request.artifactId}"
moveFile("${newRepoDir}/src/test/resources/karate", "${newRepoDir}/src/test/resources/${request.package.replace(".", "/")}/karate")

private void moveFile(String source, String destination) {
   Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(destination))
   Files.move(
      Paths.get(source),
      Paths.get(destination),
      StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING
   )
}

println "Done with archetype-post-generate.groovy"
```

Answer (score -1):

AS suggest @Devendra, something like this in your groovy script:

```
def command = "cp ${request.getOutputDirectory()}/subfolderName ./destinationFolder"
def proc = command.execute()
proc.waitFor() 
if(proc.exitValue() == 0) { 
println "Post Script: Moving files...SUCCESS";
} else{ 
println "Std Err: ${proc.err.text}"
"Post Script: ... KO, error moving files"
}
```

Where request is the instance of https://maven.apache.org/archetype/archetype-common/apidocs/org/apache/maven/archetype/ArchetypeGenerationRequest.html attached to this generation.

Or simply use variables on groovyscript:

```
def command = "cp ./${artifactId}/subfolderName ./destinationFolder"
def proc = command.execute()
proc.waitFor()
if(proc.exitValue() == 0) { 
println "Post Script: Moving files...SUCCESS";
} else{ 
println "Std Err: ${proc.err.text}"
"Post Script: ... KO, error moving files"
}
```

Comment: +1 for telling me the name of the request variable. -1 for the first script having the wrong source path, making an unnecessary shell call, using copy instead of move, and for assuming bash. It also has bad formatting.